# How do you construct interval $(a, b)$ using just intervals of the form $(b, \infty)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My attempt is $(a, b) = (a, \infty) \setminus \cap_{n=1}^{\infty} (b - 1/n, \infty)$ with $n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$; $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a < b$. Is this correct?

Comment: Looks good to me

Comment: But that just a very complicated way of writing $(a, \infty)$\ $(b, \infty)$!

Comment: @user247327 But isn't your solution equal to $(a, b]$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that works: the elements of $$\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} (b-{1\over n},\infty)$$ are exactly those real numbers which are $>b-{1\over n}$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, which is to say $$\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} (b-{1\over n},\infty)=[b,\infty).$$ And $(a,\infty)\setminus [b,\infty)=(a,b)$ as desired.

The one subtlety here (which of course you avoided, but is worth mentioning for completeness) is that one needs to pay attention to the point $b$: e.g. $(a,\infty)\setminus (b,\infty)$ does **not** work since it gives $(a,b]$ instead.